# getting extra commas when mapping over json and converting to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, template-literals

Im doing a hobby project to make a site generator which takes a json file reads is using node fs-extra module then passes that data into a function which builds an html file using template literals but i keep getting a bunch of commas in my html. Does anyone know why this is happening or can help me find a solution to fix it?

file writing using fs package

```
              <nav>
                ${
                    `<ul class='nav-list'>
                    ${navList.map(navItem =>{
                        return (`<li>
                            <a href="${
                                 navItem.folder+"/" + navItem.title +".html"
                            }">
                             ${navItem.navTitle}
                            </a>
                        <li>`)
                    })}
                    </ul>
                    `
                }
                </nav>
```

here is the HTML it outputs with the extra comma - I have another case of this which has more tags with the same comma issue (added this one for simplicity) 
OUTPUT:

```
<nav>
                <ul class='nav-list'>
                    <li>
                            <a href="./root/Index.html">
                             Home
                            </a>
                        <li>,<li>
                            <a href="./section1/Index2.html">
                             Section1
                            </a>
                        <li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>
```

This is what my terminal outputs when i log navList just above mapping it 
(after JSON.parse())

```
[ { title: 'Index', folder: 'root', navTitle: 'Home' },
```

{ title: 'Index2', folder: 'section1', navTitle: 'Section1' } ]

Thanks in advance (the above line not in a code block is part of the code block)

Comment: these commas come from the implicit conversion of the array into a string. If you don't want these commas, you should explicitely convert the array to the string you want *(join(""))*

Comment: thanks! worked out just needed to add a .join(' ') to the end of the map just like you said! @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commas come from the implicit conversion of the array into a string. If you don't want these commas, you should explicitely convert the array to the string you want (join(""))

> Would you do this before passing it into the function? Or In the template literal somehow?

I'd write it like this:

```
const renderNavItem = ({folder, title, navTitle}) => `<li>
  <a href="${folder}/${title}.html">${navTitle}</a>
<li>`;

const renderNav = (items) => `<nav>
  ${items.map(renderNavItem).join("\n")}
</nav>`;
```

you can also write a little helper to deal with that Problem:

```js
//"Rules" to convert any value into a string
const string = value => Array.isArray(value) ?
  value.map(string).join("") :
  value == null || value === false ?
  "" :
  String(value);

//a formatter that applies these "rules" to the values in a template string
const format = (strings, ...values) => strings.reduce((result, tpl, index) => result + string(values[index-1]) + tpl);

let example = format `here comes the Array: 
  <ul>${ [1,2,3,4,5].map(v => v&1? `<li>${v}</li>`: v*2) }</ul> 
  some more text ${1 < 2 && 'conditional text'} rest`;

console.log(example);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

obviously you shouldn't take this example as an example on how to build such templates, but rather a taste on the possibilities you have with template strings and tag-functions

Comment: does the \n work in html? i cant get it to work it just puts the following into the html file \n<tag>content</tag>  (so you see the \n)

Comment: @Devonnnn I've extended the answer